# what are the benefits of using arrow function instead of assign when declaring variable?

Tags: reactjs, variables, arrow-functions

I watched the video below

https://egghead.io/lessons/react-store-values-in-localstorage-with-the-react-useeffect-hook

in the beginning he wrote

```
const initialCount = Number(window.localStorage.getItem('count') || 0);
```

later he corrected this to below to optimize

```
const initialCount = () => Number(window.localStorage.getItem('count') || 0);
```

but I didn't get why it is optimized

let me know thanks in advance

Comment: Second one is a function. you can call it multiple times as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

For,

> const initialCount = Number(window.localStorage.getItem('count') || 0);

As soon as component is mounted this line will be executed which will take some time and processing power.

> const initialCount = () => Number(window.localStorage.getItem('count') || 0);

While,the above statement will be only declared because it is a function and it will be only executed once it is called. This can effect the performance.

Comment: Spot On Answer !!

Comment: you mean with arrow function way, everytime when components are rendered, it restore somewhere ??

Comment: Inshort arrow function is a function. It is not a variable that gets computed. The difference is one is function and the other one is variable.

Answer (score 0):

When we use function, it is executed only when it is called.